# BAT to delete remote file and rewrite remote registry key?

Tags: batch-file

In the company I work with, we have recently found an issue. The solution to this issue is to delete a file on the C: drive and edit a registry key. We have a large number of remote computers, and all of these computers need the fix applied. Currently, we have to remote into the computer (lets say the name of the computer is ABC1) and run a bat file that has been created.

> **BAT file:**  del "c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Symantec Shared\HWID\sephwid.xml" reg Import "h:\Shared\Symantec HardwareID
>   Fix\SetSymantecHardwareID.reg" Pause
>
> **REG file:** Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint
>   Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink] "HardwareID"=""

However, this proves to be a bit slow, because we have to interrupt the user's work flow in order to login to their PC and run the BAT file. I am a bit new to all this, so even the stuff above was a bit of a stretch for me. Is there a way to do all of this without interrupting the user? We can manually access their file system and registry and do the edits ourselves, but I was checking for an easier solution. It'd be handy if it could ASK which computer we'd like to delete the file on, but I don't know if that is possible.

Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Use group policies to deploy and run startup script (assuming that you have MS domain when you have lots of windows computers).Anyway, I'm voting to move this to serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's possible. A simple script like this should do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /p comp=Enter Computer Name or IP address: 
del "\\%comp%\c$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Symantec Shared\HWID\sephwid.xml"
reg add "\\%comp%\HKLM\SOFTWARE\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\SMC\SYLINK\SyLink" /t REG_SZ /v HardwareID /d "" /f
```

Comment: You need to run this script under account which has admin privileges on target computer of course.Also some services like RPC and Remote Registry needs to be enabled.